# Injecting class fields in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-injection

Hello all
I have a piece of software that I would like to run many different times, each for a particular value of a class field that is set in the class's constructor.
E.g, somewhere in the code is something along the lines of

```
public class Stuff
{
   private double importantVal;
   public Stuff(double val)
   {
      this.importantval = val;
   }
   public double doStuff()
   {
      return 4 * importantVal;
   }
}
```

This class and method is very far down in the program/call-stack, so I can't merely call doStuff several times by itself.
I would like to test the program for various values of importantVal, perhaps by placing them in a file and iterating over them.  I worked out the easy bit of running the program many times , but I have no good idea of how to substitute different values of importantVal.  If all else fails I can always write a script that modifies the source code, but that feels ugly and ad-hoc.  Is there a more elegant solution involving injection, or something along those lines?

Comment: how do you run the program currently? Do you run from command line or is it a web app or a webservice?

Comment: I am not sure many people will understand your question. Why can't you write a junit test case and call  call new Stuff(double).doStuff() iteratively. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you may want to look into Unit Testing.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing 

Specifically you should look at JUnit or TestNG or another testing framework

Comment: The problem is that Stuff and doStuff are very "deep" inside the application.  I didn't make that clear.  Also, I run it from the command line right now

Comment: Again, take a look at Unit-Testing.  You can test functions and classes like this anywhere in your code.

Comment: Yes, but I need to run the entire application, of which the shown class is a very small part, for each value of importantVal.  I am vaguely familiar with Unit Testing, but have not come across that capability.  Can you please direct me to a reference.

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate what the folks are trying to tell you here, here's how the testcases might look like:-

```
public class StuffTest {

    @Test
    public void testDoStuff_Zero(){
        Stuff stuff = new Stuff(0);
        assertEquals(0, stuff.doStuff());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoStuff_One(){
        Stuff stuff = new Stuff(1);
        assertEquals(4, stuff.doStuff());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoStuff_NegativeValue(){
        Stuff stuff = new Stuff(-10);
        assertEquals(-40, stuff.doStuff());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoStuff_PositiveValue(){
        Stuff stuff = new Stuff(10);
        assertEquals(40, stuff.doStuff());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoStuff_DecimalValue(){
        Stuff stuff = new Stuff(1.1);
        assertEquals(4.4, stuff.doStuff());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StuffRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = 0.0d;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            Stuff s = new Stuff(x);

            if (s.doStuff() != 4 * x) {
                System.out.print("Error, unexpected value. X=");
                System.out.println(x);
            }

            x = x + 1.22;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have multiple instances of the Stuff class? if not, perhaps you could try "injecting" the values by making importantVal static? or to inject multiple values use a List?

```
public class Stuff{

   private static List<Double> testVals = new LinkedList()<Double>;
   private double importantVal;
   public Stuff(double val)
   {
      this.importantval = val;
   }

   public static addTest(double test){
       testVals.add(test);
   }

   public double doStuff()
   {
      return 4 * testVals.removeFirst();
   }

}
```